# ArrayList.get() return null value

Tags: java, list, arraylist, null, addition

I'm starting with java and I'm facing an issue.

I create an array lsit, and add object to it. 
Then I create a method to return this object, but this method return a "null" value. 
I can't figure out how to solve this issue. 
Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at StarSystem.getPlanetString(StarSystem.java:29)
    at StartActivity.main(StartActivity.java:9)
```

here is the code:

**Main:** In here I just display data on screen:

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class StartActivity {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StarSystem starSystem = new StarSystem();

        starSystem.getPlanetString();

    }
}
```

**Planet:** this class is used to create planets:

```
public class Planet {

    final double planetMinRadius = 1000;
    final double planetMaxRadius = 100_000;
    double temperature;
    double powerReceived; 
    int radius;

    public Planet() {
        radius = 1247;      
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

}
```

**StarSystem:**: in this class, I generate a starSystem object and want to link it with a list of Planets:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StarSystem {


    final int minNumberPlanet = 3;
    final int maxNumberPlanet = 10; //10 
    int numberPlanets = 5;
    double positionX, positionY;
    ArrayList<Planet> planets;


    public StarSystem() {
        ArrayList<Planet> planets = new ArrayList<Planet>(numberPlanets);       

        for (int planetPosition = 0 ; planetPosition < numberPlanets ; planetPosition++) {
            Planet planetToAdd = new Planet();
            System.out.println("planetToAdd.toString :" + planetToAdd);
            planets.add(planetToAdd);
            Planet p = planets.get(planetPosition);
            System.out.println("p.toString : " + p);
        }
    }


    public void getPlanetString() {
        System.out.println("TEST");
        Planet a = planets.get(1);
        System.out.println("a.toString" + a);
    }


}
```

thanks in adavance for your help

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Add the constructor for the planet class at least.

Comment: I just add the Planet class

Comment: Nothing in the code you're showing so far reproduces what you're saying happens, so: prove that what you're claiming is indeed what happens by forming the [mcve] that Sweeper asked for. It's not just "for us", it's also "for you, to demonstrate to yourself that what you think is happening, is actually happening". ArrayLists are bounded, so will throw an error if `position` is a bad number, and `new Planet()` yields "not a null", so where is the _actual_ code that shows you trying to get out a planet but getting `null` back? (and please read through that link, it explains _how_ to make one)

Comment: I shared the full minimal code. I can reproduce the error with the updated code shared. Still can't find the solution. thanks for your help

Comment: I simplify the code for clarity.

Comment: `ArrayList<Planet> planets = new ArrayList<Planet>(numberPlanets);` in the constructor is **SHADOWING** the `planets` field, so the field is never assigned a value. Any good IDE would have warned you about this. *You are using an IDE, right?!?* --- Remove `ArrayList<Planet>`, so the code uses the field, not a local variable.

Comment: Yes ! It works ! Thank a lot !
Yes I use an IDE: Eclipse, but it does not show any error...
Can you recommand a better IDE ?

Comment: @AnthonyLEVILLAIN - IntelliJ. It's a great mystery of the universe that anybody ever used Eclipse given IntelliJ is both much better and older. IDK, did maybe IntelliJ not originally have the free Community Edition version?

Answer (score -1):

I see nothing wrong with your code. I suspect your problem lies in code you are not showing us.

We can make this a lesson in Debugging 101.

Do not combine clauses of code, as that makes debugging difficult. Another benefit is that the Java compiler can better optimize. So separate you new planet instantiation from adding to the list.

Drop in some `println` calls to see your values in action.

By the way, when you know the likely number of elements in a list, specify that number as an initial capacity.

```
numberPlanets = determineNumberOfPlanets();
System.out.println( "numberPlanets: " + numberPlanets ;
ArrayList<Planet> planets = new ArrayList<Planet>( numberPlanets );

for (int planetPosition = 0 ; planetPosition < numberPlanets ; planetPosition++) 
{
    Planet p = new Planet() ;
    System.out.println( "planetPosition: " + planetPosition ;
    System.out.println( "p.toString(): " + p ) ;
    planets.add( p );
    Planet p2 = planets.get( planetPosition ) ;
    System.out.println( "p2.toString(): " + p2 ) ;
}
```

Write your code to [*fail fast*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast). Whenever handing off objects between chunks of code, check their validity.

Java offers some handy utility methods to check for nulls. The method [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)) returns the first argument you pass, unless null. If null, this utility throws an exception. To customize the message of that exception, pass a message string as the second argument.

```
Planet p2 = Objects.requireNonNull( planets.get( planetPosition ) ) ;  // Another way to check for null. Throws exception if null.
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments regarding way of debugging.
I just edit my initial text so you can see the full code

Comment: I shared the full code and changed according to your remarks, but I'm still not able to find a solution. Could you please have a quick look? Thank you

Comment: I simplified the code for clarity.

Comment: With enough code in the question, the [real problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61546889/arraylist-get-return-null-value#comment108872899_61546889) has reared its head.

Comment: sorry about that, it was my first post, I will know for the next time. And I got some advices to debbug my future code ;)